# How sort this json format in react native using map function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the following JSON format

```json
{
  "name":"xyz",
  "age-group":"bb"
}
```

How to get sort out this JSON
I use the following code

```js
const array = [{ "name":"xyz", "age-group":"bb"} ]

array.map((element) => {
    Console.log(element.age-group)
});
```

I got an error:

```console
Can't find variable: group
```

Answer (score 0):

1st thing is you can't map object.
and in your case you set json object in array and then you are maping it.

so it must be like:

```
array[0].name;
```

but in second property, it has hyphen which looks like "age-group" to access object property containing hyphen is:

```
array[0].obj["age-group"] //this is return `bb`
```

so in your code it will be:

```
array.map((element) => {
     console.log(element.obj["age-group"])
    });
```

to access object property with hyphen(-) you need to use notation with square brackets.